# wbadmin crashes via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, windows-backup, vss

I'm trying to take system backup on Windows 8.1 Pro (EFI system partition + C:\ drive). It works perfectly well via Control panel however such command in command prompt fails:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:F: -allCritical -vssFull -quiet
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Retrieving volume information...
This will back up (EFI System Partition),BOOTCAMP(C:) to F:.
The Windows Backup engine could not be contacted. Retry the operation.
The remote procedure call failed.
```

Some errors in error log (sorry it's in Polish):

```
Nazwa aplikacji powodującej błąd: wbengine.exe, wersja: 6.3.9600.18437, sygnatura czasowa: 0x57acb33f
Nazwa modułu powodującego błąd: wbengine.exe, wersja: 6.3.9600.18437, sygnatura czasowa: 0x57acb33f
Kod wyjątku: 0xc0000005
Przesunięcie błędu: 0x000000000011e667
Identyfikator procesu powodującego błąd: 0x24d8
Godzina uruchomienia aplikacji powodującej błąd: 0x01d540ce4c6040b5
Ścieżka aplikacji powodującej błąd: C:\windows\system32\wbengine.exe
Ścieżka modułu powodującego błąd: C:\windows\system32\wbengine.exe
Identyfikator raportu: a17c185c-acc1-11e9-854a-7cc3a15198ba
Pełna nazwa pakietu powodującego błąd: 
Identyfikator aplikacji względem pakietu powodującego błąd:
```

Comment: I would suggest: 1, Create the directory: `C:\dumps`. 2. Download Procdump.exe from Sysinternals/Microsoft and save procdump.exe to `C:\dumps`.  3. In an admin prompt run `CD \dumps`, followed by `procdump -i -ma C:\dumps`.  Reproduce the issue and then make the first dump file if it creates 2 available.  You can then run `procdump -u` .

Comment: I got the dump. Now what?

Comment: Could you make it available?  Other option is you download the Windows SDK, and install the Debugging Tools for Windows.  From there, you can open WinDbg, configure Symbols and choose to load the dump file.   Then the analyis begins.  `!analyze -v` is the absolute minimum output.  You could share that if you go down this route.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13yY8GqvBF3rMzCtk7ZvBIP87mUHpqz52/view

Comment: This could be it: https://windowsforum.com/threads/windows-8-image-backup-fails-backup-engine-could-not-be-contacted.114876/ I got UEFI install and my recovery partition is 300 MB

Comment: Have you resoted to running `Wbadmin delete catalog` yet? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin-delete-catalog Does it help?

Comment: Just tried and it works! You can add this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just typed this command and all works back!

```
wbadmin delete catalog
```

Here's the proof:

```
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Retrieving volume information...
This will back up (EFI System Partition),BOOTCAMP(C:) to F:.
The backup storage location that you selected is on the same physical hard
disk as your operating system. If the hard disk fails, you may lose both
your system data and backup data.

The backup operation to F: is starting.
Creating a shadow copy of the volumes specified for backup...
Creating a shadow copy of the volumes specified for backup...
Creating a shadow copy of the volumes specified for backup...
Creating a backup of volume (EFI System Partition) (260.00 MB), copied (0%).
Creating a backup of volume (EFI System Partition) (260.00 MB), copied (100%).
Scanning the file system...
The backup of volume (EFI System Partition) (260.00 MB) completed successfully.
Creating a backup of volume BOOTCAMP(C:), copied (35%).
Creating a backup of volume BOOTCAMP(C:), copied (99%).
The backup of volume BOOTCAMP(C:) completed successfully.
Summary of the backup operation:
------------------

The backup operation successfully completed.
The backup of volume (EFI System Partition) (260.00 MB) completed successfully.
The backup of volume BOOTCAMP(C:) completed successfully.
Log of files successfully backed up:
C:\windows\Logs\WindowsBackup\Backup-23-07-2019_08-24-14.log
```